# How to add "N" days to smarty variable?

Tags: prestashop, smarty

I need increase a date to smarty variable. This will not be to increase the days of a current date as smarty.now if not rather to increase the days to a order date variable.

For current date the code works:

> ```
> {assign var="estimated_days" value=$smarty.now|date_format:"%u"}
> {"+5 days"|strftime|date_format:"%A %e %B"}
> ```

But using this formula in to variable it not working because shows wrong dates:

```
{assign var="estimated_days" value=$order.details.order_date|date_format:"%u"}

{"+5 days"|strftime|date_format:"%A %e %B"}
```

I tried with `{"order.details.order_date +5 Days"|date_format:'%A, %e de %B'}` and multiple formulas and the conclusion is the right order_date only is showned with `{$order.details.order_date}` variable in format 10-10-2021 but when is added the `|date_format` the captured date is as `smarty.now` (current date) and not the order date.

Maybe `{assign var="estimated_days" value=$order.details.order_date|date_format:"%u"}` is wrong?

How can I add X days in to smarty variable `{$order.details.order_date}` using `date_format` ?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

Adding a day to a variable:

```
  {assign var="estimated_days" value=$smarty.now|date_format:"Y-m-d"}
  {"$estimated_days +1 days"|strtotime|date_format:"Y-m-d"}
```

Smarty: current day

```
{$smarty.now|date_format:"%A, %B %e, %Y"}
```

Comment: sorry, I tested with {"order.details.order_date.date +1 Days"|date_format:'Y-m-d'} and this captures the date as current date instead of the date of the variable $order.details.order_date

Comment: My bad, i have tested the code and added the correct way to my answer, it works with Prestashop

Comment: nothing shows your code, I also think that if it worked will show the current date of smarty.now and not the variable date i am looking. My last try was {"$date_add +5 Days"|date_format:'%d %m %Y'} and add the days successfully but from current date. The trick maybe is adding the right value=$order.details.XXX in var

Comment: I pasted it in my demo shop, it works. Make sure to clear your store cache

Comment: you only get current date plus +1 day with your code, your code is the same i shared in my first post for current date, I am looking to add X number days and format date in to a variable date. estimated_days and smarty.now is Current date;  order.details.order_date or date_add will be always previous date (the date when the order was ordered)